# Save Wisteria during Veranda renovation

Tags: plant-care

We have a Wisteria growing along the vertical beams (with some horizontal support) of our Veranda to provide shade.

The Veranda is now up for extension/ renovation. We like the Wisteria so would like to save as much as possible of it and / or enable it to grow back as quickly as possible.

Is possible / worth it so save it, and if yes, what is the best approach?

[Edit] Images added

[image: Front]
[image: Other Side]

Comment: Do you want to preserve it in-situ? Put a picture up so we can see the size of the main stems, are there any roots visible on the surface? It's one way to get an idea of the root mass. What is the time frame of the building project and is it possible to defer construction until autumn - Finally have you got plant-friendly builders?

Comment: Goodness, 'plant friendly builders'?! I don't think they exist, do they... I'm wondering where you are in the world User12889, at least whether you're in the southern or northern hemisphere?

Comment: Is the wisteria still dormant, or has it already budded out?

Comment: Images added. Autumn not a problem as I'm in the southern hemisphere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the assumption that the main trunk/roots where it was planted is not in the way of any renovation work, then yes, it is worth trying to save it. First, see if you can extract/unwind any main stems which are in the way, and lay them on the ground directed away from where the work will be (although that may not be possible, given that builders trample everything). If you can't do that, then just cut it off wherever you need to - it would be better to do this whilst the plant is dormant, but I'm assuming its dying back now, for surely it must be autumn where you are, as its spring here the northern hemisphere. I also don't know how cold it gets where you are - if it doesn't get really cold, there might be a problem with the hard cutting back forcing new growth, which you don't want at this time of year, but so be it, it's better than ditching the whole thing. It's certainly worth giving the plant a chance - they are extremely resilient, and will come back very lively indeed even if you cut it all back to a main trunk. The only chance you'll lose it is because it hasn't become dormant, and the weather remains warm long enough for new growth to appear, but even if that gets killed back, on a very mature plant, it should survive.

It will not flower for at least next year, possibly/probably longer.

Comment: I did as suggested. Renovation is finished and it is recovering beautifully. Thanks.